# How to setup simple User Roles for Wordpress Custom Post Type

Tags: wordpress

I'm working on a system for temps/part-timers using Wordpress. To go about this I'm making a new custom post type EMPLOYEE and I need 2 corresponding users AGENT and CUSTOMER for it:

- The AGENT user can *create* and *edit* his own EMPLOYEE(s), but not edit the EMPLOYEE(s) of other AGENT(s).
- The EMPLOYEE post can be *viewed* and *commented on* by all AGENTs, CUSTOMERs and the general public,
- which also implies that the CUSTOMER user can only *view* all EMPLOYEE posts.
- The CUSTOMER user needs to be differentiated from the general public because once they hire an EMPLOYEE, the system needs to associate them with the EMPLOYEE, thus the need for the CUSTOMER to be a signed-in user.
- Finally, both AGENT and CUSTOMER users can *create/edit* their own vanilla Wordpress user profiles and sign-in with their username/password combination.

How do I execute this arrangement? The online documentation on users and capabilities had me pulling my hair and runnin around in circles. So far here's my custom post type registration, and I'm currently setting up the meta boxes for other info for this post type:

```
register_post_type( 'employee',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __('Employees','tdom'),
            'singular_name' => __('Employee','tdom'),
            'add_new' => __( 'Add New' ),
            'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Employee' ),
            'edit' => __( 'Edit' ),
            'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Employee' ),
            'new_item' => __( 'New Employee' ),
            'view' => __( 'View Employee' ),
            'view_item' => __( 'View Employee' ),
            'search_items' => __( 'Search Employees' ),
            'not_found' => __( 'No Employees found' ),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Employees found in Trash' ),
            'parent' => __( 'Parent Employee' )
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'menu_icon' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/emp_icon.png',
        'menu_position' => 4,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'supports' => array('title', 'thumbnail', 'author')
    )
);
```

I've come across Justin Tadlock's [Members](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members/) plugin (very popular on Google and forums), but I was hoping my requirements are simple enough not to use a plugin anymore. It's also a bit too much to wrap my head around.

Help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd advice a plugin, it's complicated enough

Comment: **Note to mods**: this question would be a better fit for WPSE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This really shouldn't be terribly difficult.

The first step is to create a *custom capability type* to correspond to your custom post type, via the `'capability_type'` parameter passed to [`register_post_type()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type). You're using the default, i.e.:

```
'capability_type' => 'post',
```

Set that to something else, perhaps `'employee'`, and as per the Codex, also set `'map_meta_cap'` to `true`:

```
'capability_type' => 'employee',
'map_meta_cap'    => true,
```

The next step is to add the related capabilities to your custom users, via the `$capabilities` parameter passed to your call to [`add_role()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_role). For the "employee" user role, you'll want to add `edit_employee` et al (edit_, delete_, etc.), and for the "agent" user role, you'll want to include `edit_employee` et al, along with `edit_others_employee` et al.

Comment: thanks @Chip ! i'll work on this and give you a heads up once i get it to work or i run into a roadblock. thanks again

Comment: hi @Chip am working on this part of my code again. so 'nuther question, sorry if nobbish :D so where do i put my `add_role()` call? in my `functions.php` after creating the post type? tia

Comment: I'd recommend putting it into the same callback that includes your `register_post_type()` function call.

Comment: @AnaBan could you share some more info/code from your part-timers system? i am developing a restricted exhibitors website where the ADMIN team creates all exhibitor accounts and each verified exhibitor could reserve products and services.
Regards