# How to enable a custom post type to custom user role in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, user-roles

I have created a custom post type called Course Documents using WordPress [Custom Post Type UI](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/) plugin.
Also I have created a new user role called Teacher.

```
add_role('rpt_teacher',
            'Teacher',
            array(
                'read' => true,
                'edit_posts' => false,
                'delete_posts' => false,
                'publish_posts' => false,
                'upload_files' => true,
            )
        );
```

And now I want to enable the custom post type in teacher dashboard nav menu.
I have used below code in my functions.php
but nothing happens. How can I resolve my issue?

```
add_action('admin_init','rpt_add_role_caps',999);
    /**
    add teachers capability
    */
    function rpt_add_role_caps() {

        // Add the roles you'd like to administer the custom post types
        $roles = array('rpt_teacher','editor','administrator');

        // Loop through each role and assign capabilities
        foreach($roles as $the_role) {    
             $role = get_role($the_role);               
             $role->add_cap( 'read' );
             $role->add_cap( 'read_course_document');
             $role->add_cap( 'edit_course_document' );
             $role->add_cap( 'edit_course_documents' );
             $role->add_cap( 'edit_published_course_documents' );
             $role->add_cap( 'publish_course_documents' );
             $role->add_cap( 'delete_published_course_documents' );
        }
        }
```

Comment: Found a solution: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/290090/how-to-enable-a-custom-post-type-to-custom-user-role-in-wordpress/290100#290100

Answer (score 1):

You may use this plugin for your custom post type and custom user role.

- [Capability Manager Enhanced](https://wordpress.org/plugins/capability-manager-enhanced/g)

Hope this will helps you.

For more information,

- [User Role Editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/)
- [How to setup simple User Roles for Wordpress Custom Post Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10206293/how-to-setup-simple-user-roles-for-wordpress-custom-post-type)
- [Allowing custom role access to custom post type in back end](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/186337/allowing-custom-role-access-to-custom-post-type-in-back-end)